# Wrong namespace when creating a new C# file?

Tags: c#, file, namespaces, project

I have two projects called *Hbt.DMS.BusinessLogic* and *Hbt.DMS.Web* . In *Hbt.DMS.BusinessLogic* I have a folder called *Operations*. When I try to create a new file inside *Operations* folder, it generates a wrong namespace inside the file.

```
ex: the generated namespace: Greenwich.DMS.Web.Operations
expected namespace: Greenwich.DMS.BusinessLogic.Operations
```

I noticed that this happens when I try to create new files in any folder in *Hbt.DMS.BusinessLogic* project.

What am I missing?

Comment: right click on the project, select properties...  In the Application "tab" you can set the Default Namespace for the project

Comment: You can try deleting the project and re-add it?

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you very much Bernhard Kircher and Hmemcpy for quick response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct `Default namespace` in the **Project Properties** (e.g. `Greenwich.DMS.BusinessLogic`). The visible name of the project does not necessarily have to be the same as the default namespace.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you very much for your quick response.